# ESP8266 error when compiling: TCP_MSS must be defined

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm just beginning with Arduino and ESP8266. After doing some basic things with an arduino board, some leds and sensors, I wanted to replicate them over a Mini-NodeMcu Lua WiFi-Board based on ESP-8266-12E and everything went fine. Then I wanted to try WiFi connection with this board but I cannot compile any example code, all of them compile with errors as soon as I include the ESP8266WiFi.h library.

Errors shown are:

```
#error TCP_MSS must be defined
#error LWIP_IPV6 must be defined
#error LWIP_FEATURES must be defined
#error LWIP_OPEN_SRC must be defined
```

I can't find any info on these errors. I'm using Arduino IDE and everything is updated to latest versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the lines

```
#define TCP_MSS whatever
#define LWIP_IPV6 whatever
#define LWIP_FEATURES whatever
#define LWIP_OPEN_SRC whatever
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I ended doing. Later I realized I had an old version of the Arduino IDE and updating it to version 1.8.9 solved it. Now I don't have to define neither of them.